# After API Result, Result Not SavingTo Variable

Tags: swift, api

I have made my JSON Call to retrieve the required fields, baseURL and IDURL. When I print them inside with `print("station["id"])` it works, but I need to pass those parameters in a variable. When passed, it returns nil.

Yes, I know I can make a function but this is just for testing/practice purposes.

I have changed the link for privacy purposes on the post.

```
let searchURl: URL = URL(string: "http://theAPIlink.com")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: searchURl) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    if (error == nil) {
        if let json = data {
            do {
                let content = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: []) as? [String:Any]

                if let response = content?["response"] as? [String:Any] {
                    if let data = response["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let stationlist = data["stationlist"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let station = stationlist["station"] as? [String:Any] {
                                let IDURL: String = station["id"] as! String      
                            }

                            if let tunein = stationlist["tunein"] as? [String:Any] {
                                let baseURL: String = tunein["base"] as! String
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
}

task.resume()

let fullURL: URL = URL(string: "http://theurl.com\(baseURL)?id=\(IDURL)")!

print(fullURL)
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where you set `baseURL` and on the line where you use it for `fullURL`. Then after the result of that test confuses you, do some research on what asynchronous means.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint the variable is saved. Although not saved afterwords

Comment: But note that the breakpoint on the `let fullURL...` line is reached well before the breakpoint on the line `let baseURL...`.

Comment: In addition to that, the `baseURL` and `IDURL` variables are not visible to your `fullURL` declaration, because they're local to the respective scopes that they're declared in. I can only assume that the reason this even compiles is because the class that contains this method has some properties that are coincidentally named the same as those two variables, and your `fullURL` initializer is accessing those by mistake.

Comment: Even if I do a print(baseURL) after task.resume() it still returns nil

Comment: You need to do your `print(baseURL)` *inside the `URLSession` handler*. Immediately after `task.resume()` the download has only just *started*. It hasn't finished until the handler is called.

Comment: This is all under view did load therefore local scope

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the line `let baseURL: String = ...`. It's inside an `if let` block, and is only visible in that scope. As soon as you hit the curly brace `}` on the next line, that variable is not accessible anymore.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka ok, now I get it. therefore how can I save it, does it have to be a global variable?

Comment: Don't use globals if you don't have to. I'd just declare another `func` that takes both of those variables, and call it from the `URLSession` handler with the values you get in the handler. Then in that new `func`, you can do whatever needs to be done with the URL.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I will do that, and when you say URLSession Handler can I just pass in those two variables in that one if let statement to the function?

Comment: It depends on whether it makes sense to proceed if either of them is nil. If not, I'd just `guard let` both of them and throw an error if they're nil. Otherwise, keep them optional as `String?`, and pass them to the new `func` in that form.